# Can we Record Tuxedo with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, tuxedo

we have an application (client/server) which uses a GUI to communicates to the Tuxedo server. it uses TCP, FTP protocols for communication. can we use JMeter or any other open source tool for that?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter does support both FTP and TCP protocol via [FTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#FTP_Request) and [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) elements provided, so the answer is "yes", you can use JMeter.

You can also find [How to Send Control Characters Using the JMeter TCP Sampler](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/268778-how-to-send-control-characters-using-the-jmeter-tc) guide useful as it's rather common problem and frequently asked question.

However I doubt that JMeter can record TCP-based traffic types. You can try pointing your client application to server via JMeter HTTP Proxy server to see what requests it'll catch.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but the tricky point is "request is TCP and the response some times in FTP". can you please elaborate 2 things. 1. How to record TCP traffic 2. iam getting 0 bytes for TCP sampler

Comment: JMeter currently doesn't record TCP traffic, you'll need to capture it via sniffer tool or consider switching to Grinder tool which has TCP recording proxy. http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html